First paragraph of first column runs the same width as single column first page
I'm using the overleaf template provided by a journal that I am submitting to that is found here. When I add my own text, the first page looks fine but the first paragraph of the second page (which is multiple columns) ends up being the same width as the first page width and running into the adjoining column. I also get an underfull box warning at the end of that paragraph. Using \indent or \newpage does not solve this problem. It also is not an issue in the following paragraphs. Any tips would be appreciated. Image of my compiled output attached for reference. Thanks!


Please add a compilable [mre] to your question which allows us to reproduce the problem.
